# How to require password when accessing a folder on Windows

Tags: windows, security, permissions, passwords, password-protection

My question is about Windows and no networking (it's not about a shared folder, just a local folder, example `C:\Users\john\musics\myMusics`).

All software to "lock" folders just hide the folder, and ask password to "show" the folder again.

I don't want to hide a folder and then to show it by opening the program and give the password, it's too long, annoying.

What I want is the folder to be visible BUT when accessing to it (by double click, for example), a prompt that asks for a password to access to its content. Just that. Simple.

Comment: Is the for any access by the owner AND other local users — or — do you mean, require password if OTHER local users attempt to access?

Comment: Just for local user. Imagine that you log into your local account Windows 10 and your have on your desktop a folder. This folder has to be protected by password. It's a custom request

Comment: So I presume you mean that a single user, ‘john’ in your example above, remains always logged in, but you want to restrict access to your “music”.  In that case ‘john’ would be known as the Owner.    I found this on google, apparently not completely secure, but may serve your purpose: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/password-protect-folder-windows-10

Comment: Thank for the search. I've already seen this content (the page you gave in your last comment) and the problem it's that it open command prompt. The ideal way i want is to right click on folder > set password for LOCK and when double click asking for password. But I suppose it's not possible on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

I have find a software, but you could need to pay for it. I have downloaded it and tested. This could be a little different from your requirements.
https://password-folder.en.softonic.com/

When you open the software, you can add the folders into it to lock the folders. And on the right-top of the software, you can click the options, to select if you want to hide the locked folders or other permissions.

When you double-click the folder locked, it will tell you that you don't have the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Windows 10?

Unless you're really set on being able to view filenames for password-protected files without authentication, there is a native workaround. You can effectively accomplish this by [creating and formatting a new partition](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-and-format-a-hard-disk-partition-bbb8e185-1bda-ecd1-3465-c9728f7d7d2e) then [setting up encryption with BitLocker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-on-device-encryption-0c453637-bc88-5f74-5105-741561aae838), which will allow you to add a password.

You can then add the folders you want private to that drive.

Note: If you don't have access to the "Turn on BitLocker" feature, you might not have Trusted Platform Module on your computer. If you have Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise, you can [enable BitLocker without it.](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-bitlocker-encryption-windows-10)